# How to get lowest value for 2 duplicate entries in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table, that contains various products for a store. They each have an identifier, which is universal and distinct for every product, it is set by the manufacturer. But since I am getting the price lists from several wholesalers to get the lowest price possible, I have more than 1 row with the same identifier.

I would like to have a way to get the whole product list showing every product only once,but for the duplicate products show the lowest price possible. How to do this?

I thought of doing a SELECT on every product to check if it is the single on, but that would be inefficient. I have also thought about some array manipulations, but that too would add a lot of time.

*Background info: I currently have about 30k products, which is planned to rise to about 100k soon.*

A standard query for my product table looks like this:

```
SELECT productId,productIdentifier,productWholesaler,productPrice FROM `products`
```

The `productIdentifier` is the part that has the same value for products from multiple wholesalers, but the `productPrice` is never the same for 2 duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT productId, productIdentifier, productWholesaler, MIN(productPrice)  
FROM `products`
GROUP BY productId, productIdentifier, productWholesaler
```